# Getting error computing VCI in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, geocoding, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, vegetation-index

I have tried to use this code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fjohanneswilk%2Ftest%3ATest_13%20MODIS%20VCI%202

but there is the following error message:

> Line 170: MonthlyMAX.subtract is not a function

Can you help me?

Error is in:

```
var Mndvi2 = monthlyNDVI.map(
        function(img) {
        var vci = img.select('NDVI')
                          .subtract(MonthlyMIN).divide((MonthlyMAX.subtract(MonthlyMIN))).multiply(100)
                          .rename('vci');
                          
        return img.addBands(vci);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

With changes in following lines submitted complete code (not commented) works (you cannot use an image collection in your function as a single image and roi is the "geometry" for your chart).

```
var MonthlyMIN_img = MonthlyMIN.mean();
var MonthlyMAX_img = MonthlyMAX.mean();

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Calculation of VCI //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var Mndvi2 = monthlyNDVI.map(
        function(img) {
        var vci = img.select('NDVI')
                          .subtract(MonthlyMIN_img).divide((MonthlyMAX_img.subtract(MonthlyMIN_img))).multiply(100)
                          .rename('vci');
                          
        return img.addBands(vci);
  }
);

var VCI = Mndvi2.select('vci')
print(VCI, 'VCI')


print(ui.Chart.image.series(VCI , roi , ee.Reducer.mean(), 5000));
Map.addLayer(VCI.first())
```

Complete code is:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8cf7fc6c27bbd63ca4294d3955fd2277

and, result of running it is as follows:

[image]